# Continuity and Product Spaces

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, products

I have the following basic question regarding continuous functions.

Is the following statement correct?

> Fix nonempty toplogical spaces $A, B, C, D$ with $A \times C$ and $B \times D$ endowed with the product topology. Also, fix functions
>
> \begin{align*} h & : A \times C \to B \times D ,\\ f &: A \to B ,\\ g &: C
>  \to D , \end{align*}
>
> with $h := (f, g)$. Thus, if $h$ and $f$ are continuous, then $g$ is continuous.

I know that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $h$ is continuous, while if $h$ is continuous it is not necessarily the case that both $f$ and $g$ are continuous. What about this 'intermediate' case?

Thanks a lot in advance for any feedback.

Comment: how are $h,f$ and $g$ related?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment and sorry, I left it implicit. Now I edited to clarify.

Comment: If you are using the product topology and $h$ is continuous, I think that its components $f,g$ are also continuous, as they are the composition of $h$ (continuous) with the projections (which are continuous for the product topology, as it is the inital topology for the projections).

Comment: Do you consider the empty set a topological space? Presumably the product has the product topology.

Comment: @user469053 Thanks for the feedback: I updated the question.

Comment: Why not begin by saying that $A,B,C,D$ are topological spaces?

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for the feedback: I updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $h$ is continuous if and only if $f,g$ are.

For one direction, assume $f,g$ are continuous and pick a net $(x_\alpha,y_\alpha)_\alpha$ in $A\times C$ converging to $(x,y)$. Then $\lim_\alpha x_\alpha=x$ in $A$ and $\lim_\alpha f(x_\alpha)=f(x)$ by continuity of $f$. Similarly, $\lim_\alpha g(y_\alpha)=y$. So $\lim_\alpha h((x_\alpha, y_\alpha))=(x,y)$, and $h$ is continuous.

For the other direction, assume $h$ is continuous. Fix any $y\in C$ (here is where the non-emptiness of $C$ becomes necessary). Define $a:A\to A\times C$ by $a(x)=(x,y)$. Define $b:B\times D\to B$ by $b(u,v)=u$. Then $a,b$ are continuous and $f=b\circ h\circ a$. Thus $f$ is also continuous, since it is the composition of continuous functions. By symmetry, so is $g$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is something I know, but this is not what I asked.

Comment: It answers your question. It also corrects an incorrect statement you made within the question.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry and thanks a lot.  I was aware of a characterization result for a function $f : X \to Y_1 \times Y_2$ and of another result which states that if $f_i : X_i \to Y_i$ is continuous for every $i \in I$, then $f : X \to Y$ is continuous with $X := \prod_i X_i$ and $Y := \prod_i Y_ i$, but I was missing the other direction of this latter result (everything with the product topology).